# href tags in jsp's and passing data by clicking on href tag

Tags: java, html, jsp, url-rewriting, href

this is my program

```
<form method="post">
Movie Name :<input type="text" name="movie"/><br>
Hero:<input type="text" name="hero"><br>
Director:<input type="text" name="dir"><br>

<a href="insert.jsp">Insert</a>
<a href="update.jsp">update</a>
<a href="delete.jsp">Delete</a>
```

when i click on the any of the href link the values of above text boxes should also to be carried to that particular jsp page
 i used getparameter method but i am not getting what i entered but they are taking null values

Answer (score 3):

This is because your href elements are simply redirecting to these other pages -- the form's data is scrapped.

What you want to do is allow the form to be submitted -- you will receive the values in your Servlet's doPost() implementation, and in that method, you should then redirect to the page by, perhaps, adding the values in the URL, for instance:

```
insert.jsp?movie=jaws&hero=hercules&director=spielberg
```

The values will then be available to that page.

EDIT: based on my latest comment, to do this without POST/servlets, your code would look like that with jQuery enabled:

```
<form method="get" id="myForm">
    Movie Name :<input type="text" name="movie"/><br>
    Hero:<input type="text" name="hero"><br>
    Director:<input type="text" name="dir"><br>

    <a href="insert.jsp">Insert</a>
    <a href="update.jsp">update</a>
    <a href="delete.jsp">Delete</a>
</form>
<script>
$('#myForm A').click(function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent the link from actually redirecting

   var destination = $(this).attr('href');
   $('#myForm').attr('action', destination);
   $('#myForm').submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: i dont want to use servlet page iwant to redirect to another jsp or html page only so that that page sholud get the values

Comment: No problem, but then the way will be to put, in your <form> attribute: method="get" action="insert.jsp" -- this will redirect to the page and put the values in the URL (like in my example), but the problem we have now is that we have 3 pages to which we can forward, so you'll have to use JavaScript to dynamically set the 'action' attribute of your <form> element before submitting, assigning which page you actually want to forward to based on user input or click.