# how can I pass data by clicking on href tag in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I am in `index.jsp` and I want to pass some data after clicking `href` tag. The code of this page is as following:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            a{   
                padding: 10px !important;width:200px;
                text-decoration:none !important;        
                background-color: #0B70BE;
                background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center center , rgb(11, 112, 190) 0%, rgb(11, 112, 190) 100%) !important;
                border-radius: 2px !important;
                border: 2px solid rgb(43, 125, 185) !important;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 13px !important;
                font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
                height: 26px !important;
                text-shadow: none !important;
                color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#myForm1').click(function (e)
            {
                e.preventDefault(); // prevent the link from actually redirecting
                 $('#myForm1').submit();
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <%
            String name = "1231"; 
            int rollNo = 121;
        %>

        <form method="get" id="myForm1" action="hello.jsp">
            <Input type="Hidden" name="name"  id="name" value="<%=name%>"> 
            <Input type="Hidden" name="rollNo"  id="rollNo" value="<%=rollNo%>"> 
            <a href="hello.jsp">Please Enroll Finger 1</a> 
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

After clicking `href` tag, I will go to `hello.jsp`. In that page, I want to retrieve `name` and `rollNo` value. So I have this code for `hello.jsp` page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <%
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            String rollNo = request.getParameter("rollNo");
            out.println("Student name "+name+"<br>");
            out.println("Student Roll No is "+rollNo);

        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

After clicking `href` tag in first page, I go to `hello.jsp` page. But in 2nd page, I am getting the value of `name` and `rollNo` as **null**. I have got the following output:

```
Hello World!

Student name null
Student Roll No is null
```

I have taken help [from this link .](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23914441/6379197)  I cant understand why I am getting null value in 2nd page. How can I resolve this error? Please help me.

## Updated Information

I have inspected code of `index.jsp`. THe code is as follows :

[image]

Comment: You are not sending any value to next page

Comment: I have specified value in  form tag .  see this code : <Input type="Hidden" name="name"  id="name" value="<%=name%>">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hidden values are inside the form, so you need a form submit to submit the values to the next page. If you directly put a page in the href attribute, the browser will go to that page without doing any form submission.

Therefore, you need to put javascript code in href instead to trigger the form submit action, like below.

```
    <form method="get" id="myForm1" action="hello.jsp">
        <Input type="Hidden" name="name"  id="name" value="<%=name%>"> 
        <Input type="Hidden" name="rollNo"  id="rollNo" value="<%=rollNo%>"> 
        <a href="$('#myForm1').submit();">Please Enroll Finger 1</a> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to do this by using submit button like this.

```
  <form method="get" id="myForm1" action="hello.jsp">
        <Input type="Hidden" name="name"  id="name" value="<%=name%>"> 
        <Input type="Hidden" name="rollNo"  id="rollNo" value="<%=rollNo%>"> 
        <Input type="submit" value ="Please Enroll Finger 1"> 
    </form>
```

by this control is sent to hello.jsp with data.